# Rails: Math not computing correctly. It's off by .00000000000001

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails app is not doing math correctly. I think this has something to do with the variable types (int vs float) but not sure what's wrong.

The root problem is this method in my Stat model:

```
def lean_mass
 self.weight * 0.01 * (100 - self.body_fat)
end
```

Where

```
Stat.weight = 140
Stat.body_fat = 15
```

it returns `119.00000000000001` instead of `119`.

However, where

```
Stat.weight = 210
Stat.body_fat = 15
```

it returns `178.5`, the correct number.

Anyone know why it's throwing in that small decimal?

The datatype for weight is integer and body_fat is decimal if that helps.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This is due to the CPU error, a mathematical error of minimal amounts that is caused by the way certain data types are represented in the memory. The `float` and `double`  data types in most languages are optimized for calculation performance and memory footprint, which pays with the possibility of CPU errors. Furthermore, these errors are specific to different hardware and not trivial to overcome. There are other data types and methodologies to compensate this, but at the price of higher CPU/Memory usage, and are slower.

Comment: @Ivjis is definitely neither a "CPU error" nor a mathematical error. It's just the way IEEE 754 defined floating point operations. These are not wrong, they just follow different rules than math on real numbers does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers. And furthermore floating-point operations cannot precisely represent every arithmetic operation. This leads to many surprising situations.

A simple example that shows this behavior:

```
0.1 + 0.2
#=> 0.30000000000000004
```

I advise to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You can avoid most of this problems by using `BigDecimal` instead of floats:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
BigDecimal.new('0.01') * 140 * (100 - 15)
#=> 119.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the best way to fix what I have then? I want to make sure my numbers are accurate.

Comment: Another option would be to round the resulting number to the desired accuracy, e.g. `(self.weight * 0.01 * (100 - self.body_fat)).round(2)` to round to 2 decimal digits.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at ruby `BigDecimal`

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html

For example, try:

```
sum = 0
10_000.times do
  sum = sum + 0.0001
end
print sum #=> 0.9999999999999062
```

and contrast with the output from:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

sum = BigDecimal.new("0")
10_000.times do
  sum = sum + BigDecimal.new("0.0001")
end
print sum #=> 0.1E1
```

Comment: Note that `0.to_d` is a shorter way to get the same result as `BigDecimal.new("0")`